# Installing new package in TeXstudio

Tags: packages, installing, texstudio

How to install a new package in TeXstudio?
Spesifically I want to install TikZ package to draw automata.

Comment: No you do not ;-) You want to install `tikz` in your LaTeX installation, which has nothing to do with TeXstudio. It would be more helpful to us to know which LaTeX distribution you are using. And perhaps which operating system.

Comment: Ah ok. I was confused about that. Now it's clear. I use MiKTeX on Windows 7. 
Addition to my question, which TikZ package that is intended to draw automata (state diagram). I searched in ctan, and I am not sure which one.

Comment: You need it all. Harddisk space is cheap, install everything (this is one of the reasons I recommend texlive over miktex, it installs everything by default)